# Python Packaging and Resources

Tags: python, user-interface

Okay so I have been having trouble creating python.exe and running them on other computers. Does anyone have good resources on what executable converter to use and any other good tips. So far I have been using pyinstaller and I can run standalone scripts but not GUI applications.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is too vague and will likely not be answerable. Firstly, you probable do not want to create **the file `python.exe**, because you get that file simply by installing Python. I think you want to know how to **convert your python script into an executable file**. This is not always needed for python projects. See [the official docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/). Also "it does not work" is no helpful problem description. State what you tried and what happens when you run your GUI program. I suggest you [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, pyinstaller, [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), [cx_freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) are a few alternatives. I have used many of them before, and have never got any problem with creating GUI apps using those.

If you want simple solution, you can use [GUI2EXE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gui2exe/) it's a GUI frontend for cx_freeze that will package your script into an exe file.

Comment: Which out of p2exe and cxfreeze do you prefer

Comment: py2exe. It has other versions like py2app for MacOS, while py2exe converts it for Windows OS.